# Docker and windows registry

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core application that loads some configuration parameters from windows registry.

```
var registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32)
```

The application runs in windows docker and registry key is always null.

Is it possible to read registry value when application runs in docker?

Comment: What is the base image you are using for your dockerfile? I think it needs to be a Windows based image to access the registry. If you are using a Linux based image then it won't work.

Comment: I use windows container. For linux container i get exception about registry is not available in linux when i just try open specific key. But for windows there is no any exception. Registry key is just null. Maybe is it need some additional settings for external services?